# How to redirect URLs with a trailing slash to the non-slash variant (with exceptions)?

Tags: regex, nginx, server, webserver

I have a few problems to set up NGINX so that all URLs with a trailing slash (/) redirect permanently to the variant without a slash. The problem is that this directive should happen for all URLs except those that start with `/backend`.

**For example:**

```
https://example.com/service/ --> https://example.com/service
https://example.com/service/one/ --> https://example.com/service/one
https://example.com/backend/ --> https://example.com/backend/ (should not redirect)
```

I am currently using this directive:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    [...]

    location ~ ^/(?!backend)(.+)/$ {
        return 301 $1$is_args$args;
    }

    [...]
}
```

unfortunately the following error occurs here:

```
https://example.com/service/ --> https://example.com/service/service
```

Can someone help me solve this regex mystery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return 301 $1$is_args$args;` expression is missing a leading `/` so that the browser interprets the redirect as relative to the current URI. `service` relative to `/service/` is `/service/service`.

Either capture the leading `/` in `$1` or add it explicitly to the `return` statement.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/(?!backend)(.+)/$ {
    return 301 /$1$is_args$args;
}
```